# If I did not pick any image it will have an error message

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload an image in firebase storage using flutter, but when I did not choose any image there will be an error.

The error started to happen when I put the code that will upload the image. If I also remove the null check, it will also show an error message that it needs a null check.

```
        import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:project/storage_service.dart';

    class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
      const UserProfile({super.key});

      @override
      State<UserProfile> createState() => _UserProfileState();
    }

    class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Storage storage = Storage();
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Profile Picture'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                          allowMultiple: false,
                          type: FileType.custom,
                          allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg'],
                        );

                        if (results == null) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(content: Text('No selected file.')));
                        }

                        final path = results?.files.single.path;
                        final fileName = results?.files.single.name;

                        // when I added this line of code there will be an error when I did not choose any image
                        storage
                            .uploadFile(path!, fileName!)
                            .then((value) => print('done'));
                      },
                      child: Text('Upload profile picture')))
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message?

Comment: I have updated my answer below to provide an example solution for null checking

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is currently missing in the question, I can only guess that it has todo with the forced optional unwrapping (!) in this function call

```
storage
    .uploadFile(path!, fileName!)
    .then((value) => print('done'));
```

You should check these values for null before accessing them.

For example via

```
if (path != null && fileName != null) {
    storage
        .uploadFile(path!, fileName!)
        .then((value) => print('done'));
} else {
    print("path or fileName does not exist") // Potentially because none was selected...
}
```